# How can I convert this to pass markup validation?

Tags: javascript, html, w3c-validation

This keeps coming up with a validation error:

```
$("#preview").html('<div align="center"><img src="/ajaximage/loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/></div>');
```

It says: document type does not allow element "div" here

How can I get around this?

Comment: Try using `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead of `<` and `>` maybe?

Comment: @Ian — That will break the script in `text/html` documents

Comment: Either (1) Stop using XHTML as it is far more trouble then it is worth for almost everybody or (2) Read http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/

Comment: @Quentin Yeah, it was a long shot. I should've tried in a jsfiddle first (which I just did and found out doesn't work)

Comment: First, what is your doctype? Second, what is the HTML context for this code? The error indicates you are putting a div where it cannot be, perhaps in the HEAD section or not otherwise inside the BODY tag, etc. Your code as posted is fine, its the context that seems to be wrong.

Comment: @Quentin Wait, why? Why would it break the script? It doesn't work when using `.html()`, but it didn't/shouldn't break. Or am I missing something?

Comment: make the script tag `<script type='text/javascript'><![CDATA[ ... your code ]]></script>`

Comment: @BrianDHall — The code is clearly JavaScript, so the error can only be caused by having an inline `<script>` in an XHTML document.

Comment: @Ian - Because if it is parsed as text/html then scripts contain implicit cdata so entities won't be decoded so the script will render a `<` character instead of starting a tag.

Comment: @Quentin But what I suggested wouldn't **break** the script, it would just not **work** (HTML isn't appended, it's text that looks like HTML), right? I think I'm just misunderstanding too much of what the problem really is, and don't know enough about it

Comment: @Ian It won't break the script in the "will throw an error" sense, it will break it in the "won't do what it is supposed to do" sense.

Comment: @Quentin Ahh I see, okay. I was wondering how that would throw an error... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `//<![CDATA[` in the script tag, I got this to validate as XHTML 1.0:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        $("#preview").html('<div align="center"><img src="/ajaximage/loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/></div>');
    //]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Ignore the part where I leave out many things (like a jQuery library, etc.).

But mainly, I would suggest using the HTML5 DOCTYPE unless you have a reason not to.